# Retrieving OAuth2 Client from Google Passport Strategy

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am authenticating in my node.js (express) using Passport.js' Google Strategy: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/google/. The whole process works fine and I can authenticate, login, logout, handle tokens and all that jazz.

Now I have extended the scopes to include access to the authenticated user's calendar, and profile by creating a separate client and performing what I need to do in the API, however that seemed a little bizarre since it seems to be that I should be able to retrieve the already established OAuth2 client for subsequent requests. Has anyone face a similar issue?

Side note: I also got the authentication working using Service Accounts, probably that's a better route to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sticking to the JWT approach which was anyway the better alternative for my scenario.